# Segmentation fault while trying to insert objects to nullpointers array

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

This is a part of a class I need to implement.

```
template <class Element, class Compare = std::equal_to<Element>>
class UniqueArray {
    Element** data;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int max_size;
public:
    explicit UniqueArray(unsigned int size);
    UniqueArray(const UniqueArray& other);
    ~UniqueArray();
    unsigned int insert(const Element& element);
```

I can't use STL (only exception is `std::equal_to`).

I implemented the constructors as follows :

```
template <class Element, class Compare>
UniqueArray<Element, Compare>::UniqueArray(unsigned int size):
    data(new Element* [size]), size(0), max_size(size){
}


template <class Element, class Compare>
UniqueArray<Element, Compare>::UniqueArray(const UniqueArray& other):
    data(new Element *[other.size]), size(other.size), max_size(other.max_size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        *data[i] = *other.data[i];
    }
}
```

`data` is actually an array of pointers. 
each pointer points to an Element.

This is my implementation of `insert` function which causes `SEGFAULT`

```
template <class Element, class Compare>
unsigned int UniqueArray<Element, Compare>::insert(const Element& element){
    if (size >= max_size){
        throw UniqueArrayIsFullException();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if((Compare(), *data[i]) == element){
            return i;
        }
    }

    *data[size++] = element;
    return size;
}
```

The test im running is this :

```
static void testInt() {
    typedef UniqueArray<int, std::equal_to<int>> intUA;
    // Test ctor
    unsigned int size = 4;
    intUA ua(size);
    assert(ua.getSize() == size);
    assert(ua.getCount() == 0);
    // Test insert
    ua.insert(4);
    unsigned int index = ua.insert(1);
    ua.insert(5);
    assert(ua.insert(1) == index);
    ua.insert(2);
    assert(ua.getCount() == 4);
    ua.insert(2);
    // Test UniqueArrayIsFullException
    try {
        ua.insert(3);
    }
    catch (intUA::UniqueArrayIsFullException& e) {
        return;
    }
    assert(0);
}
```

Test fails at the first call to `insert` and points that the problem is in line `*data[size++] = element;`

Comment: What is `(Compare(), *data[i]) == element` supposed to do? Create the function object before the loop, `Compare cmp;` then call it in the loop: `if(cmp(*data[i], element))`

Comment: shouldn't I call its default constructor by : ```compare_func = Compare()``` ?

Comment: `Compare` is the type so you can do `Compare compare_func = Compare();` if you want, but `Compare compare_func;` is shorter. The main thing is how you use it: `if( compare_func(arg1, arg2) )` is the proper way. Your current code won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a copy of the element and store it at `data[size++]`, change

```
    *data[size++] = element;
```

To

```
    data[size++] = new Element(element);
```

---

Bonus hint: the following probably won't work the way it's meant to work:

```
    if((Compare(), *data[i]) == element)
```

But you have a nice test for it, so it should catch it.

Comment: As for the segmentation error , it is working now :) 
About the ```Compare()``` , Would you suggest that I create an instance of this object ? for example whenever a function need to compare two Elements:
```compare_func = Compare()
compare_func(Element a, Element b)```

Comment: Yes. Like this: `Compare cmp; ... if (cmp(*data[i], element)) ...` or `if (Compare()(*data[i], element)) ...`

Comment: shouldn't I call its default constructor by : ```compare_func = Compare()``` ?

Comment: In `Compare cmp;` a default constructor is automatically invoked.

Answer (score 1):

When you first construct a
`UniqueArray<Element, Compare>`,
you do not initialize any of the pointer in the array.

If you are *lucky,* they are all null pointers.

So the first time you try to insert an element via

```
*data[size++] = element;
```

the array entry `data[size]` is a null or uninitialized pointer.
What did you expect to happen when you evaluate `*data[size]`?

Comment: If I wanted to initialize all the pointers in the array to null pointers this code suffice ? 
```for(int i = 0; i < max_size; i++){
        data[i] = NULL;
    }```

Comment: I like the explicit initialization from the viewpoint of general good practices (though `nullptr` is the preferred symbol now), but note that dereferencing a null pointer does not work any better that dereferencing an uninitialized pointer (though the error message can be a little easier to recognize). You need to get actual pointers to actual objects into your array. There are ideas about this in other answers.